# How to check a returned value of a callBack?

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition, gestures

I
 want to know what is the returned value from `onFling` so that to 
perform certain action. But, I do not want to perform that action from 
within the `onFling` body because some of the objects I use will not be 
accessible. As the code mentioned below states, I want to call certain 
method from inside `setTouchableInfoDialog()` based on the returned 
value from `onFling`. how can I achieve this?

Java_Code:

```
private boolean setTouchableInfoDialog(LinearLayout 
infoReportContainer, Dialog mDialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "@setTouchableInfoDialog(): Inside 
                  setTouchableInfoDialog()");

        if (infoReportContainer == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "@setTouchableInfoDialog(): LinearLayout 
                       infoReportContainer Is NULL");
            return false;
        }else {
            final GestureDetector mGestiredetector = new 
GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new mSwipeGestureDetector());
            infoReportContainer.setOnTouchListener(new   
OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i(TAG, 
 "@setTouchableInfoDialog()->onTouch(): Binding the 
  LinearLayout infoReportContainer"
                            + " To the 
  GestureDetector");
                    return 
    mGestiredetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            });
        }
        return true;

    }

class mSwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 150;

    /**
     * onFling callback is dependent on onDown() callback, meaning, 
      onDown() is called BEFORE onFling() and based on the value
     * returned from onDown(), onFling() will be called or not. So, 
      onDown() MUST always be implemented AND return TRUE in order
     * to, onFling() executes, otherwise it will be unreachable.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float 
            velocityX, float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "@onFling(): Fling Gesture Detected");
        try {
            if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
            Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("@onFling(): ", "Up Swipe");
                return true;
            }else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 

            Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("@onFling(): ", "Down Swipe");
                return true;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return false;
    }
```